# Error JOIN con Symfony

Tags: symfony3, join, symfony, dql

Tengo una relación entre 2 tablas Orders y Users desde el campo `user_id` y `id` respectivamente.

Realizo esta consulta:

```
$dql="SELECT u, o
      FROM BackendBundle:Orders o
      JOIN o.users u";
$query=$em->createQuery($dql);
```

Y este es el error que me muestra:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 68 near 'u': Error: Class BackendBundle\Entity\Orders has no association named users

Y no sé cómo puedo corregir este error.

Answer (score 0):

Realizando más pruebas encontré la solución. Era solo poner `user` y no en plural `users`.
La consulta queda así:

```
$dql="SELECT u, o
      FROM BackendBundle:Orders o
      JOIN o.user u";
$query=$em->createQuery($dql);
```